# Node.js: Get Response Time

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, node.js

How can I know the response time of a URL?

I'm using `http.get()` to make an HTTP GET request.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no builtin function or value to get the response time.

But you can easily get the value yourself.

```
var http = require('http');
var start = new Date();
http.get({host: 'google.com', port: 80}, function(res) {
    console.log('Request took:', new Date() - start, 'ms');
});
```

**EDIT**

Since V8 also supports the new ES5 `Date.now()`, using that instead of `new Date()` would be a little bit cleaner.

Comment: The OP wasn't clear about "response time" -- to first response, or for the entire content to be delivered. And do in danger of stating what may be obvious to many: the node code here reports the response time to receipt of headers.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not looking for a programmatic solution, load up your friend and mine, Firefox with Firebug installed.  When you bring up Firebug, select the "Net" tab and you will see the response times of all requests on the page.  Hover over a time and you get a popup breakdown of where the time went -- DNS Lookup, Wait Time, etc.