# Node.js. Get time of HTTP query

Tags: node.js, http

I'm a .NET developer and newbie in Node.js, so I will be very grateful for your understanding and help.

I have some code, that logging an HTTP query time:

```
var sTime;

var httpReq = http.request(requestOptions, function (httpRes) 
{   
    httpRes.on('end', function () 
    {
        var diffTime = (sTime) ? new String(new Date() - sTime) : '';
        log('diffTime: ' + diffTime);
    }); 
});

httpReq.on('socket', function (reqSocket) 
{
    sTime = new Date();
});
```

I receive `diffTime: 0` in log file sometimes, that isn't possible. I can try to use another way to log query's time, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052035/node-js-get-response-time), but I want to find the reason of zero time.

Comment: Do you have another request beginning at the same instant that overwrites `startTime`?

Comment: Code above is putted into method, that is called many times (let 100) by `setTimeout` method with 200ms interval. I seem understood there are no threads and all variables are shared. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Without having the rest of your actual code, it's a little hard to test your issue. Here's a similar method that will display the time difference.

```
var request = require("request");

setInterval(function(){
    doRequest();
}, 200);

function doRequest() {

    var startTime, diffTime;

    //Start the timer.
    startTime = new Date();

    request("http://www.google.com", function(err,res,body){
        diffTime = ( new Date() - startTime );
        console.log(diffTime);
    });

};
```

EDIT - see explanation here
http://nodeio.ninja/http/measuring-http-request-times-in-nodejs/